# Android app with off-site processing

Tags: android, webserver, offsite

I'm wondering what would be a good way to build an Android application with offsite processing.  Essentially I am going to record an input (audio recording or photo), and then send it to a computer I have online (securely - probably using HTTPS).  I then will have the computer process the data and send back a response.

Essentially this is a Shazam like application, except everywhere I look to how Shazam works they talk about the processing algorithm, not the process.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you just described? Capture on the device, post it to an offsite server, then poll for a result.

Comment: I'm new to Android development, so although I'm taking time the time right now to get up to speed with syntax, any examples of a similar procedure would help.

Answer (score 0):

If your server processing may take time, you can use [Push Notification](http://techtej.blogspot.com/2010/10/android-c2dm-messaging-server-push-for.html) to tell the application that you are done on the server side. The application can then get the result instead of holding up the connection for too long.